# Selecting similar records

Tags: mysql

Please consider the following records:

1. John Doe
2. Gohn Doe
3. Peter Almond
4. Anna Lee
5. Danna Lee
6. Simon Clark
7. Don Doe

I have been trying to figure an SQL Select statement that will retrieve only the records that have some similarity (score to be determined). In the example above, the intended query should return rows 1,2,5,6 and 8. I have tried looking at `MATCH AGAINST`, `LEVENSHTEIN`, but these functions work in searches where an input is provided. in my case, no input is provided. What i am trying to accomplish is detect duplicate records across my table.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a self-join to compare pairs of records. Here's a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ghkCVASHTsw5pfyySEQ9G4/0

```
  SELECT a.name, b.name
    FROM tbl a
    JOIN tbl b ON a.name > b.name
   WHERE compare(a.name, b.name) < threshold
```

`compare(a,b)` is a comparison function of your choice. You could use the [Levenshtein distance](https://gist.github.com/Kovah/df90d336478a47d869b9683766cff718) between strings. Or you could use `SOUNDEX(a.name) = SOUNDEX(b.name)`. Or anything else that does the fuzzy comparison you want.

The `ON` clause in my example avoids duplicate comparisons and self-comparisons.

Comment: Hi Jones. This works, but I tried for a large data set (2.000 records), and after 40 minutes, the query was still running. Is there any way to mak the query less expensive?

Comment: Levenshtein is one of the  hairiest of hairy functions. You're running it 2000 x 2000 / 2 times, and it's not fast.  Maybe you could do `WHERE ABS(LEN(a.name) - LEN(b.name)) < 5 AND levenshtein()` to prune the search down a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @O. Jones ! I used the same concept above, the only difference is that I did not use `LEVENSHTEIN`, instead,  I used `LEFT(a.name,4)=LEFT(b.name)` in the `Where` clause, so that it displays records with the same starting and ending strings. It works for me.